# "None" shows up with print line and input in basic code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to define a variable with an input in one line then print the newly assigned variable value concatenated to the original print line.

```
num = int(input(print("Enter an integer: ", end='')
print(num)
```

The output always contains a "none" like

```
Enter an integer:None23
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

The `None` in this case is coming from the return value of the print statement.  `input` prints the prompt itself, so you don't need to do that explicitly.

```
num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
```

Comment: And the reason for `None` being printed, is that `input` uses the return value from `print`, which is `None`.